# How to print API response in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, azure-devops

There are libraries for Node.js and Python from Azure DevOps. I'm familiar with JavaScript and I was trying to learn Python. I'm trying to create an automation using Azure DevOps python package.

In JavaScript, after getting a response, I'm using console log to see the response to check how it is formatted and what values it has as shown below.

[JavaScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7C5V.png)

But when I try the same in Python, I got below message. How can I print the response in Python to see the format of response?

<azure.devops.released.core.core_client.CoreClient.GetProjectsResponseValue object at 0x1036a6820>

[Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVb6K.png)

Comment: please, NO screenshots of text ... add the actual text instead

Comment: convert the response to string and then print

Comment: Can you show the imports from your python code? Just want to confirm the libraries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As you might expect... It's simple:

```
import json

results = {
     "first_name":"Mike"
}
print(json.dumps(results))
```

It uses the built in json package to convert the dictionary to valid json.

This assumes you have the response as a dictionary.  The json package will support multiple types of objects to json, and it will throw an error for you if it doesn't support the type of object you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using requests package

```
    import requests
    
    ///
    print(response.text)
    ///
```

should help you to view response values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like as below:

```py
import json
import requests

response = requests.get({URL}, headers={headers}, json={request body})

# Print status code of the API request
print("Status: {0}".format(response.status_code))

# Print the response body (JSON type) of the API request
print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above suggested methods didn't work for me. But I tried as below and the output is what I was expecting.

```
pprint.pprint(vars(APIResponse))
```